# Addition/Deletion records based on method argument

Tags: java

I have one method for addition and deletion of the account records. It has method argument based on which addition or deletion happens.

Below is method

```
char ADD = 'Y';
char DELETE = 'N';
private void updateAccountDtls(AccountDtlsDTO accountDtlsDTO, char addOrDeleteRecord){
    if (ADD == addOrDeleteRecord) {
        //account addition related processing
    }
    else if (DELETE == addOrDeleteRecord) {
        //account deletion related processing
    }
}
```

which is consumed in switch like below

```
switch (action) {
        case SET:
            updateAccountDtls(accountDtlsDTO,ADD);
            break;
        case RESET:
             updateAccountDtls(accountDtlsDTO,DELETE);
            break;
        }
```

from performace perspective is this good practice to use character instaed of string for Yes/No?

Comment: soo ... what about booleans? Or an actually typesafe enum?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Performance wise you're not going to notice the difference.

There is a far better solution available to you though. That is to have 2 separate methods altogether.

You already have a switch statement before calling the method in which you know that it will be a delete or an add. This makes it really easy to just call the right method.

Having separate methods that each do a specific thing makes the code easier to read and maintain later on.